# how can I make rvm create my gemset at capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, rvm, capistrano

I am trying to use capistrano to create my rvm gemset.

I use the rvm-capistrano gem.

Even I explicitly try to create it at setup, capistrano shell command looks like this:

```
rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3-p194@vatax' -c 'rvm use 1.9.3-p194@vatax --create'
```

which obviously fails with the error message:

```
Gemset 'vatax' does not exist, 'rvm gemset create vatax' first, or append '--create'
```

In fact I expected the gem to be able to create the gemset for me, but if not at least I would like to use a non-rvm shell to create the gemset within capistrano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not yet supported in the gem, there is a ticket to add support for it - https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/issues/8

For now you could use a task that installs ruby, it also takes care to create gemset, when ruby is already installed it will just create the gemset:

```
before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby'
```

More information you can find in the RVM docs: https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/

Comment: well I did have this line in my deploy rb still it didn't create the gemset when using deploy:cold. If i say before 'deploy:update', it works for both deploy:cold and deploy.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like as 2013-01-07, you can do this:

```
before 'deploy', 'rvm:create_gemset'
```

See https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a gemset for each application I deploy, so I need to create multiple gemsets. This is how I do it:

```
set :application, 'my-application-name'
set :user, 'my-username'
run "~#{user}/.rvm/bin/rvm gemset create #{application}"
```